# Spanning user information across multiple EJBs

Tags: java, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

With javax.security.Principal you can retrieve the user information at any point by injecting the `EJBContext` with `@Resource`.

What I am trying to do is add extra information which would be specific to my application and to my users as part of the `Principal`. I also tried to include this information in the `contextData()` of the `EJBContext`, but this only lasts for the EJB lifecycle rather than in multiple EJB calls.

Is there any way of extending the `Principal` to add any extra information? I would prefer not to use ThreadLocal or modify all my EJBs signature to pass this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked around this one. Custom `Principal`s can be created in JBoss AS. It is enough with creating a class that implements `java.security.Principal` and add custom attributes and getters/setters.

Then, when configuring the login module (e.g. DatabaseServerLoginModule) a module-option in the login-config.xml file just add a `principalClass` option:

```
<application-policy name="my-security-domain">
     <authentication>
     <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
          <module-option name="principalClass">com.custom.security.MyCustomPrincipal</module-option>
...
```

Now the problem is that due to an existing bug in JBoss, a call to an injected `EJBContext.getCallerPrincipal()` will not return the custom Principal but a plain instance of SimplePrincipal! But good news is that this can be solved by the following JAAS code that allows the inspection of the EJB container authentication info:

```
try {
      Subject subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
      Set<Group> subjectGroups = subject.getPrincipals(Group.class);
      Iterator<Group> iter = subjectGroups.iterator();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Group group = iter.next();
        String name = group.getName();
        if (name.equals("CallerPrincipal")) {
          Enumeration<? extends Principal> members = group.members();
          if (members.hasMoreElements()) {
            context = members.nextElement();
            myCustomPrincipal = (MyCustomPrincipal) context;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (PolicyContextException e) {
        ....
    }
```

I wrapped the above code in a POJO that I can inject in my EJBs to get the Principal similarly as the EJBContext class does.